# Omit file extension from slug

Tags: bash, markdown, jekyll, git-bash, hugo

I am using this bash script to add a markdown file name as a slug in the front matter. However, I would like to omit the extension `.md` and retain the name only e.g. `foo.md` I retain `foo`. Could anyone advise me on how to make this script work?

```
for f in $(grep --include=*.md -riL "slug:" /your_directory/); 
do sed -i "/date:.*/aslug: \/$(basename $f)\/" $f;
done
```

Comment: You'll need to show the initial file with some sample data in it so we can reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of [`basename`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/basename.1.html) on my Ubuntu machine will strip a suffix if you provide it, e.g.

```
basename path/to/some.md .md
#=> some
```

Try changing your `sed` command accordingly:

```
for f in $(grep --include=*.md -riL "slug:" /your_directory/); do
    sed -i "/date:.*/aslug: \/$(basename $f .md)\/" $f;
done
```